# Variable text Replace

Tags: c#

I have this simple text variable

```
<ul class="disc">
                <li><a href="/free-openvpn-account/VPNBook.com-OpenVPN-Euro1.zip">Euro1 OpenVPN Certificate Bundle</a> </li>
                <li>Password: <strong>8ruFatha</strong></li>                
            </ul>
```

In this text i need to extract only `Password: <strong>8ruFatha</strong>` string replace not work but this is a variable text.

It is possible?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
string extraction = text.SubString(text.IndexOf("Password:"), 34)
```

This finds password: in the string and then takes 34 characters of the string into the new string extraction. If it isn't going to be fixed to 34 characters then I recommend setting the end of the substring using another IndexOf()

Comment: Using string methods to parse html is really a very bad idea. At least if the input is dynamic.

Answer (score 3):

Usage of regular expression for parsing HTML is [not very good idea](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html). I suggest you to use [HtmlAgilityPack](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack) for that (available from NuGet):

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(yourHtmlString);
var li = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//ul[@class='disc']/li[2]");
string password = li.InnerHtml; // you can check if li is not null
```

Provided xpath selects `ul` element with class equal to `disc` and then gets second list item of that list.

Answer (score 0):

[Regex msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
 foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(answerString, @"<strong>(.*)</strong>"))
{
   //match.value - <strong>8ruFatha</strong>
}
```

answerString - your html